# How to dynamically access an object given a string with its name

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm looking to control typing in a Tkinter entry widget to have only numeric value in it.
I have seen many questions on this, none answering my actual problem. (Sorry if I missed the right one...)
I had something working with binding, but could not handle cases where user would keep a key pressed for example. So I decided to go to valide, and I'm blocked when it comes to access an object by it's name. I guess it would be a problem I may encounter again, so looking for a solution to it.

[EDIT 2 : sample of code with different frames better fitting my actual structure]

```
import tkinter as tk
from NumFormat import *

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=(self.register(NumHandler.NumValidate),
                                                        '%S', '%W', '%s')).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Open page one",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Open page two",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo)).pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is page one").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=(self.register(NumHandler.NumValidate),
                                                        '%S', '%W', '%s')).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

and in a second module (called NumFormat in this example) :

```
class NumHandler():
    def NumValidate(keycode, MyEntry, valuetocheck):

        if keycode in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
            return True

        if keycode in [",", "."] and len(valuetocheck) == 0:
            MyEntry.insert(0, "0.")
            return False

        if keycode in [",", "."] and "." in valuetocheck[:-1]:
            return False

        if keycode in [".", ","]:
            MyEntry.delete(0, "end")
            MyEntry.insert(0, valuetocheck[:-1] + ".")
            return False

        return False
```

As you may see, the way to access the frame name in the function handling the number format would also come as a string. Hereby my question : how to access the object by it's name ?

I obviously have an error message, as using "register", "Myentry" variable in the NumValidate function is a string, not an object.

Would you have any idea on how to solve this ?

Thank you all,

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: well, to be fair, tkinter widgets do have names. They are normally hidden from view, but fundamentally every widget has a unique name.

Comment: What does this mean: _"as I can also access my frame only by it's name"_? Your code doesn't have a frame in it.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. First you asked about accessing an entry widget, and then you edited the question to ask about the validation being turned off. Ask about one or the other, but not both. And yes, it is expected behavior for the validation to be turned off if you change the value within the validation function.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well noted for the questions. I stay on accessing the widget by it's name then ! When I say I can access the frame by it's name, it is because I may have different frames, so the frame's name would have to be dynamic also. Due to my lack of knowledge, and in order to be as concise as possible, I put my example in a single "root" frame, but in fact it could be root1, root2, root3, ... If I wanted to pass it in the function via register, it would turn to be a string also.

Comment: A frame is a very specific type of widget. The window itself isn't normally called a frame. If you need to root window, there's a way to get that given any other widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, then here is the problem : how to access that "any other widget" ? I guess if I found answer to that, I would also have answer to my question, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `root.nametowidget()` method.

However, it looks like it's time for you to jump into the world of making your own classes.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Jacques(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        cmd = (self.register(self.NumValidate), '%S', '%s')
        self.config(validate="key", validatecommand=cmd)

    def NumValidate(self, keycode, valuetocheck):

        if keycode in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
            return True

        if keycode in [",", "."] and len(valuetocheck) == 1:
            self.delete(0, 'end')
            self.insert(0, "0.")
            return False

        if keycode in [",", "."] and "." in valuetocheck[:-1]:
            return False

        if keycode in [".", ","]:
            self.delete(0, "end")
            self.insert(0, valuetocheck[:-1] + ".")
            return False

        return False

root = tk.Tk()

myEntry = Jacques(root, width=40)
myEntry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yes I guess it will be time for me to think to those kind of solutions ! I'll see how I can implement that in my actual code. (frames are already classes called by an other class, but guess won't be a problem) I'm acting as the beginner I am, which is solving problems one by one, not being able to see th whole picture.